# haskell syntax error in operator usage

Tags: haskell

on ghci I want to use functions as infix functions.
For example, I want to use the function div like this

```
3 'div' 2
```

but after do that on ghci, my ghci shows Syntax error message like this

```
<interactive>:3:3:
    Syntax error on 'div'
    Perhaps you intended to use -XTemplateHaskell
```

Is it normal? cause I've seen that kind of usage several times.
And if it isn't normal, what I have to do?

Answer (score 4):

Use backticks instead of single quotes.